# Unwanted fields added to translation

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a node with only 2 fields to translate (regular fields, not paragraph fields).

When I create a translation job (with tmgmt), I got those 2 fields (nice) and 2 others coming from a non translatable paragraph field.

I have followed all the rules for translating paragraphs (in this case, not translating)

`$node->my_paragraph_field`  is not set as translatable

`my_paragraph_field` support only one paragraph type which is not set as translatable in `admin/config/regional/content-language`

**Note**: looks like the 2 fields wrongly added in the translation job are the ones I have added "at the end/by after" to the paragraph type.

If someone have some clue to explain me where to check to understand how tmgmt is adding those 2 fields, it could help me with my debugging tool to find where is the bug.

**edit to add**

For one of the unwanted field, I have 2 config:

`field.storage.paragraph.field_calc_comment.yml` which contains `translatable: true` and

`field.field.paragraph.calc.field_calc_comment.yml` which contains `translatable: false`

If I change the first 'true' by 'false' and re-import the config, my problem is solved... I do not have the final explanation but I feel better